# (How) can firebase hosting be used as reverse proxy?

Tags: firebase, reverse-proxy, firebase-hosting, posthog

Tools like posthog require to [setup a reverse proxy](https://posthog.com/docs/advanced/proxy/vercel) to be used properly, and with Vercel for example, this can be easily done with :

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/ingest/:match*",
      "destination": "https://app.posthog.com/:match*"
    }
  ]
}
```

(How) can I achieve the same in firebase hosting? I tried rewrites and redirects with the following configs, without success...

```
    {
      "source": "/ingest/**",
      "destination": "https://app.posthog.com"
    },
```